# Access routing table in storing mode of RPL (Contiki / Cooja)

Tags: contiki

1. I am able to successfully run sample code (../examples/6tisch/simple-node) where rpl-lite is implemented and after every 60 seconds root of the network print its routing table. As it uses rpl-lite, only root node stores a routing table.
2. I am looking for a sample code for implementing (storing mode) in this program and print the routing table of each node every 60 seconds.

*I have added "MAKE_ROUTING = MAKE_ROUTING_RPL_CLASSIC" in the Make File to enable RPL-Classic*

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include "sys/node-id.h"
#include "sys/log.h"
#include "net/ipv6/uip-ds6-route.h"
#include "net/ipv6/uip-sr.h"
#include "net/mac/tsch/tsch.h"
#include "net/routing/routing.h"

#define DEBUG DEBUG_PRINT
#include "net/ipv6/uip-debug.h"

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS(node_process, "RPL Node");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&node_process);

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS_THREAD(node_process, ev, data)
{
  int is_coordinator;

  PROCESS_BEGIN();

  is_coordinator = 0;

#if CONTIKI_TARGET_COOJA || CONTIKI_TARGET_Z1
  is_coordinator = (node_id == 1);
#endif

  if(is_coordinator) {
    NETSTACK_ROUTING.root_start();
  }
  NETSTACK_MAC.on();

  {
    static struct etimer et;
    /* Print out routing tables every minute */
    etimer_set(&et, CLOCK_SECOND * 60);
    while(1) {
        PRINTF("Routing entries: %u\n", uip_ds6_route_num_routes());
      PROCESS_YIELD_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));
      etimer_reset(&et);
    }
  }

  PROCESS_END();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These steps worked for me:

1. Add `MAKE_ROUTING=MAKE_ROUTING_RPL_CLASSIC` to the Makefile to ensure RPL Classic is used; storing mode is on by default.
2. For convenience, add includes and defined that allow to use the Contiki-NG logging module:

```
     /* Log configuration */
     #include "sys/log.h"
     #define LOG_MODULE "App"
     #define LOG_LEVEL LOG_LEVEL_DBG
```

3. Add this code to the `while(1)` loop:

```
      LOG_INFO("Routing entries: %u\n", uip_ds6_route_num_routes());
      uip_ds6_route_t *route = uip_ds6_route_head();
      while(route) {
        LOG_INFO("Route ");
        LOG_INFO_6ADDR(&route->ipaddr);
        LOG_INFO_("/128 via ");
        LOG_INFO_6ADDR(uip_ds6_route_nexthop(route));
        LOG_INFO_("\n");
        route = uip_ds6_route_next(route);
      }
```

Output on the root node:

```
01:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: App       ] Routing entries: 7
01:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: App       ] Route fd00::205:5:5:5/128 via fe80::205:5:5:5
01:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: App       ] Route fd00::204:4:4:4/128 via fe80::204:4:4:4
01:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: App       ] Route fd00::208:8:8:8/128 via fe80::203:3:3:3
01:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: App       ] Route fd00::203:3:3:3/128 via fe80::203:3:3:3
01:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: App       ] Route fd00::207:7:7:7/128 via fe80::203:3:3:3
01:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: App       ] Route fd00::206:6:6:6/128 via fe80::203:3:3:3
01:00.382   ID:1    [INFO: App       ] Route fd00::202:2:2:2/128 via fe80::203:3:3:3
```

Output on a forwarder node:

```
01:00.899   ID:3    [INFO: App       ] Routing entries: 4
01:00.899   ID:3    [INFO: App       ] Route fd00::208:8:8:8/128 via fe80::206:6:6:6
01:00.899   ID:3    [INFO: App       ] Route fd00::207:7:7:7/128 via fe80::206:6:6:6
01:00.899   ID:3    [INFO: App       ] Route fd00::206:6:6:6/128 via fe80::206:6:6:6
01:00.899   ID:3    [INFO: App       ] Route fd00::202:2:2:2/128 via fe80::202:2:2:2
```